# Still activate PayPal PLUS - Access not allowed in the ordering process

Tags: paypal

**Current status:**
A REST API app was created at PayPal Developer. The data was stored in our own shop system. The message "Access not allowed" is displayed during the ordering process.

**Background:**
Previously, PayPal PLUS had to be activated in addition to the creation of the app. The previous link now links to the PayPal Checkout page. Since my code is probably not compatible with PayPal Checkout, I want to continue using PayPal PLUS.

**How can I continue to activate my PayPal PLUS account?
How can I tackle the "Access not allowed" message?**

Answer (score 0):

What version of Plus are you attempting to integrate? There are two different versions, one for DE and one for MX or BR.

From your profile I assume Germany. Here is the archived guide: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/de/

It is no longer available for new integrations you should use a PayPal Checkout integration such as https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/

Comment: Yes, I use the version for Germany.

It's a pity that PayPal PLUS no longer works for new integrations.

Do I have to adapt a lot or all of the source code for the integration of PayPal Checkout, is there a summary?